# is there a way to clone a run-time program to another server

Tags: c++, clone, dynamic-linking, boost-extension

Suppose I'm running a small program on the server. for example, a random number generator and sending the result to a client every second. I know that my server is about to be turned off. Is there a way to clone the program to another server so that the client doesn't notice it?

ideally i would want to save the dynamic object of the small program, send it to another server and re-link it with another server using dynamic linking. If that is possible then the question is how to save/hibernate that small program.

another obvious solution is to serialize the all states of the project and send it to another server but that would involve changing the small program, which is not desirable.

I'm not even sure what keywords to search for.

(i would like to avoid system calls, if possible. if not then it's fine.)

**update (1)**
the defult platform is linux but i'm also interested in embedded systems and nacl

Comment: search for `clustering`

Comment: @suspectus can you be more specific? i have experience using mpi and boost.mpi

Comment: You want failover technology that supports server shutdown whilst maintaining service. A cluster network will provide exactly that.

Comment: Search for "hypervisor".

Comment: You don't mention the platform.